# Why does the FormatException returned by a TypeConverter for an ushort-type refer to Int16?

Tags: c#, .net-core, typeconverter

I am writing my code in C# and .NET Core 2.0.5. When using a TypeConverter for the ushort-type, and a conversion fails, the FormatException-message refers to Int16, rather than UInt16. Can anyone explain this to me?

The other types I tested this with (decimal, double, float, int, long, short, uint, ulong), returns the expected typename in the error message.

To show my point, here is a unittest that will fail. The error message says "badvalue is not a valid value for Int16.".

```
    [Fact]
    public void FailingToConvertUShort_GivesFormatExceptionMessage_WithCorrectType()
    {
        // Arrange
        var badvalue = "badvalue";
        var typeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(ushort));

        try
        {
            // Act
            var result = typeConverter.ConvertFrom(context: null, culture: new CultureInfo("en-GB"), value: badvalue);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Assert
            Assert.Equal($"badvalue is not a valid value for {typeof(ushort).Name}.", ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is the output from the test:

> Expected: ···t a valid value for UInt16.
>
> Actual:   ···t a valid value for Int16.

Comment: First of all catch (Exception ex) stops not only on converter errors. It stop with OutOfMemory, InvalidOperation, DevideByZero and anything else you cant even imagine. Put catch (FormatException) if you expect to get FormatException

Comment: Just to confirm: you're not *really* relying on this in production code, right? This is just an easy way to demonstrate the issue? You should, in general, never rely on the textual contents of any exception. (Even so, the message has the expected contents on .NET Framework, so this is likely a bug in Core only.)

Comment: From the question is it seen code example enough for demonstation should be:  Debug.WriteLine(typeof(ushort).Name);

Comment: Well, thank heavens for open source. The bug is [fairly obvious](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/src/System/ComponentModel/UInt16Converter.cs): line 18 reads `internal override Type TargetType => typeof(short);`, rather than `internal override Type TargetType => typeof(ushort);`. Likely some poor copy-pasting.

Comment: For good measure, [here's the offending commit](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/6f48f1959c292aa78fe38902f62e9dd33436c6c5). It was correct initially (and still is, on the .NET Framework).

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy I know catch(Exception ex) catches all, but I just wrote the test to prove my point. I agree that I could have provided a simpler example to prove my point.

Comment: @JeroenMostert No, I am not relying on this in production. I stumbled upon the issue when I was writing a unit test for something completely different, and was curious as to why the message did not reflect the type being used.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Great job finding the bug! If you provide it as an aswer (rather than a comment), I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `UInt16Converter` (the type you get back with `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(ushort))`. Specifically, [this line](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/251d65c237aa26b49bc91bac25012340a93e64de/src/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/src/System/ComponentModel/UInt16Converter.cs#L18):

```
internal override Type TargetType => typeof(short);
```

should obviously read `ushort`  rather than `short`. This bug was introduced as part of a [cleanup commit](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/commit/6f48f1959c292aa78fe38902f62e9dd33436c6c5#diff-4934d3603a94cae7e5f39a5bd171982a) to use expression-bodied members.

The message of the exception seems to be the only thing affected. It also selects a slightly different code path in `TypeConverter.ConvertTo` when converting to strings, but this has no actual effect on the formatting of `UInt16` values. Note that the [tests](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter/tests/UInt16ConverterTests.cs) for this class don't cover this: they only verify that `ConvertFrom` throws on an invalid value, but not what type of exception, or the contents of the message. (The latter is almost certainly by design, since .NET exception messages are localized.)